# Arrange list to numpy array in matrix form

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I got a list:

```
rs = list([[(0, 167, 159, 0), (1, 168, 160, 1)], [(0, 167, 159, 1), (1, 168, 160, 0)]])
```

and I want to arrange it into numpy array in matrix form, thus I wrote the following code:

```
import numpy

rs = list([[(0, 167, 159, 0), (1, 168, 160, 1)], [(0, 167, 159, 1), (1, 168, 160, 0)]])
k = 2
j = 0
h = 0
ars = []
element = list(rs)
ck_dist_m = numpy.array([[]], ndmin = 2)

while j <= k - 1:
    while h <= k - 1:
        rp = numpy.array(element[j][h][3], ndmin = 2)
        ars.append(rp)
        h = h + 1
    else:
        h = 0
        ck_dist_m = numpy.vstack(ars)
    j = j + 1
print ck_dist_m
```

I want the result to be:

```
[[0, 1],
 [1, 0]]
```

But the script above gave this:

```
[[0]
 [1]
 [1]
 [0]]
```

How to edit the script to get result in matrix form?

Comment: Could you explain how `list([[(0, 167, 159, 0), (1, 168, 160, 1)], [(0, 167, 159, 1), (1, 168, 160, 0)]])` relates to `[[0, 1], [1, 0]]`?

Comment: In the while loop I extract the third element in the sublist, and try to store them in matrix form.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> In the while loop I extract the third element in the sublist, and try to store them in matrix form.

Here is a much more direct way to achieve this:

```
>>> numpy.array(rs)[:,:,3]
array([[0, 1],
       [1, 0]])
```

Comment: It's a more directive way!